# Magento 1 how to setup recurring payment initial fee on the fly?

Tags: magento-1.9, recurring-billing

I need to set recurring payment's initial fee during check out. So that I can charge customer the time when order is placed.

Does anyone know how or point me a direction? thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I need to make it clear that the recurring payment is made against paypal gateway shipped with default Magento. My solution is to twist a bit of method **submitRecurringProfile** resides in **Mage_Paypal_Model_Pro.php**. So I override it with **MyCompany_ModuleName_Model_Paypal_Pro.php** so that I can make changes to **submitRecurringProfile** without mess up the core file.

```
public function submitRecurringProfile(Mage_Payment_Model_Recurring_Profile $profile,
                                       Mage_Payment_Model_Info $paymentInfo
) {

    $profile->setData('init_amount', 100);
    parent::submitRecurringProfile($profile, $paymentInfo);
}
```

With about function in place, initial fee will be set to 100.